# Changing the response options in Outlook with MATLAB actxserver

Tags: matlab, outlook, appointment

Below is a simple example of a MATLAB actxserver for sending Outlook invitations that works without any problems. However, my question is how to turn off the reply options. Required Attendees do not have to reply, whether they are present or not.

```
out = actxserver('outlook.Application');
appointment = out.CreateItem('olAppointmentItem');
appointment.Subject = 'My Subject';
appointment.Body = 'Appointment in MATLAB';
appointment.Start = '13/01/2022 09:00:00';
appointment.End = '13/01/2022 09:30:00';
appointment.RequiredAttendees = 'one@email.com; two@email.com';
appointment.Save();
appointment.Send
out.release;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to turn off the `ResponseRequested` property, from the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.responserequested

> Returns a Boolean that indicates True if the sender would like a response to the meeting request for the appointment. Read/write.

i.e. in your case, `appointment.ResponseRequested = false;`